# Rails .where for array isn't working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm looking to find records where `@messages.visiblity` (array) matches the `current_user.id` with this simple call:

```
@messages = Message.where(visibility: [current_user.id])
```

However it's not returning anything!  So frustrating.  Here's a sample of a message that should be in that `@messages` collection:

```
2.3.3 :007 > Message.last
  Message Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "messages".* FROM "messages" ORDER BY "messages"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Message id: 35, subject: "hello!", content: "can you see this", user_id: 40, created_at: "2020-08-06 03:22:59", updated_at: "2020-08-06 03:22:59", visibility: ["55", "49"], active: true>
```

Here the current user.id is 49.

It wont add that message to the `@message` instance until all user.ids are met, not just the *one* id that is 49.  The record will be added to `@messages` if I do this:

```
@messages = Message.where(visibility: ["55", current_user.id]) #DON'T WANT THIS!
```

But that's ridiculous.  Everywhere I'm looking says the first call should work, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my Message schema:

```
create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "subject"
    t.string "content"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "visibility", default: [], array: true
```

and here is the form that collects the data:

```
<%= form_with(model: @message) do |form| %>
<%= form.check_box(:visibility, {:multiple => true}, u.id, nil) %> - <%= u.email %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why are you using an array instead of an association?

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
Message.where('visibility @> ARRAY[?]::string[]', ["49"])
```

or this:

```
Message.where("'49' = ANY(visibility)")
```

Comment: In addition, you can check the [rails documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array) where they suggest the same that @Spikie's answer

Answer (score 0):

Following is the way how we can do it in databases irrespective of if database supports Array or not.

There is a pattern how serialized array is stored in database.
`["55", "49"]` will be stored as `"55"\n "49"\n` (or `55\n 49\n`)

So you can search using `LIKE` operator

```
@messages = Message.where("visibility LIKE ?", "% #{current_user.id}\n%")
```

OR

```
@messages = Message.where("visibility LIKE ?", '% "#{current_user.id}"\n%')
```

Note: There is space between `%` and `#` in `% #{current_user.id}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also

```
Message.where("visibility && array[?]",current_user.id.to_s)
```

I am casting `current_user.id` to `STRING`, because `visibility` is a `STRING ARRAY` and it cannot be compared to integer value of ID

You can also specify it as below:

```
Message.where("visibility && array[?]",[current_user.id.to_s])
```

Or with Multiple value array as below:

```
Message.where("visibility && array[?]",['55','49'])
```

Multiple values are compared as AND operation.